# Trying to display a random video on page load

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to load a random video on page load. This is some javascript that I threw together that I thought might work. I'm not that familiar with javascript, so there might be a much easier way to do this... Any ideas?

```
function random_video {

    var string1 = '<div class="span4"><h3 class="meet">Meet the Makers</h3><iframe width="100%" height="200" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Ig-DbfPoz3o" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>';

    var string2 = '<div class="span4"><h3 class="meet">Meet the Makers</h3><iframe width="100%" height="200" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/estPhyfBGho" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>';

    var string3 = '<div class="span4"><h3 class="meet">Meet the Makers</h3><iframe width="100%" height="200" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/6JL4hpnZklk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>';

    var number = Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1);

    if ( number == 1) {
      document.write(string1);
    } else ( number == 2 ) {
        document.write(string2);
    } else ( number == 3 ) {
        document.write(string3);
    }

};
```

Comment: Your if/else condition needs some more ifs (e.g. `else if(...`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [play random video on each visit/refresh with iFrame javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63653799/play-random-video-on-each-visit-refresh-with-iframe-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would be more generalizable and easier to add more videos if you use an Array:

```
var videos = [
    'Ig-DbfPoz3o',
    'estPhyfBGho',
    '6JL4hpnZklk'
];

var index=Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length);
var html='<div class="span4"><h3 class="meet">Meet the Makers</h3><iframe width="100%" height="200" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + videos[index] + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>';
document.write(html);
```

Comment: The randomization logic is off a little bit. It should just be `Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length)`. This will give out random numbers that are 1 less than the length of the array which is perfect since the array length (in this example) is 3, but the index of the third entry is `2`.

Comment: ew! `document.write()`!