# Display random youtube video

Tags: html

I have the following code to display a youtube video as the background of my site

```
<iframe frameBorder="0" height="100%" width="100%"
src="https://youtube.com/embed/ID?autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1">
```

How can I make ID be selected from an array of ID's, i'm new to this but think i need to use a javascript script with arrays to select a random one?

Thanks

Solved I used this https://gist.github.com/alishutc/a6b1b0fc11a28a627897

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript random youtube video autoplay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22128689/javascript-random-youtube-video-autoplay)

Answer (score 0):

try using javascript

```js
var id = ['WfmeUdQb4ek', 'CJdOiXwCyzY', '6pilrScSXms', 'TiFthD8t_DI'];

//console.log(id);
setTimeout("changeVideo()", 5000);
var x = 0;

function changeVideo() {
  console.log(id[x]);
  //console.log("https://youtube.com/embed/"+id[x]+"?autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1");
  document.getElementById("video").src = "https://youtube.com/embed/" + id[x] + "?autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1";
  x++;
}
```

```html
<!--<iframe frameBorder="0" height="100%" width="100%"
src="" id="video"></iframe>-->
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen id="video"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks, how do i insert this into my website?

Comment: add `<script></script>` in javascript code it will work

Comment: Thanks, if you dont mind one more question with https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FOO5LYE8B5CC iframe height 100% doesn't seem to work

Comment: You can only add 100,200 not with % in iframe

Comment: H can i make a script using the onkeypress event to pick a new random video. i could do f5 but don't want to refresh entire page. Here is the code https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FOO7PUPAXOW3 Thanks @Bhargav

Comment: i have no any idea for that what you want to do..?

Comment: I want to refresh the video without refreshing the entire website.